# Getting Error while doing correlation in R

Tags: r, pca

I have a code where i am extracting a CSV file in R .
I have close to 40-50 variables and i want to reduce the dimensions for further analysis .
Most of the columns in Dataset are either INT ,FACTOR OR NUM.
The typeof my dataframe BO is list.
The error on the below code is 'Error in cor(BO) : 'x' must be numeric'

```
heatmap(cor(BO),Rowv = NA,Colv = NA)
```

Comment: you probably have factors or characters in your `BO` object.

Comment: i do have lot of factors in my Dataframe. 
What should be done in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have non numeric values in your `data.frame`, which you need to exclude:

```
heatmap(cor(BO[, sapply(BO, is.numeric)]),Rowv = NA,Colv = NA)
```

**Explanation**

With `sapply` you loop through all columns of your data frame (which is internally stored as a `list` with the in-variant that all elements must be of the same length) and apply the function `is.numeric` to the columns. You get back a logical vector for all columns whihc are numeric. With this vector you can now select the proper columns.

**Example With a BuiltIn dataset**

```
## does not work for the same reason
heatmap(cor(iris))
# Error in cor(iris) : 'x' must be numeric

## works
heatmap(cor(iris[, sapply(iris, is.numeric)]))
```

Comment: Error: unexpected ']' in "heatmap(cor(BO[, sapply(BO, is.numeric]"

Comment: Fixed, forgot the closing bracket. If your code would have been complete, I could have tested it before ;)

Comment: It worked. Thanks  :)  
But i want to know how can i reduce the variables from my Dataset using PCA

Comment: I am using the following command to run PCA
BO_pca <- prcomp(BO[, sapply(BO, is.numeric)], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

Comment: It results in following error 
Error in prcomp.default(BO[, sapply(BO, is.numeric)], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE) : 
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance

Comment: This is another problem (which can be solved easily too), so please post a new question for that.